# Android SQLiteException: No Such Column

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Im trying to update my Database, But every time i get an error saying No such column. Ia m still a beginner in Android, So any help would be appreciated.

THank you in advance.

Here is my 2 Database classes:

AreaMonitoringDB:

```
public class AreaMonitoringDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "AreaMonitoringDB";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AreaMonitoring.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "AreaMonitor";
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_FLAG= "enable1";
public static final String COL_FLAG2 = "enable2";
public static final String COL_FLAG3 = "enable3";
public static final String COL_NUMBER = "tel_number";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_AREAMONITOR = "create table "
        + TABLE_NAME + " (" 
        + ID + " integer primary key, " 
        + COL_FLAG + " integer not null, " 
        + COL_FLAG2 + " integer not null, " 
        + COL_FLAG3 + " integer not null, " 
        + COL_NUMBER + " text );";

private static final String DB_SCHEMA = CREATE_TABLE_AREAMONITOR;

public AreaMonitoringDB(Context cx){
    super(cx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DB_SCHEMA);
    //init(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Upgrading database. Existing contents will be lost. ["
            + oldVersion + "]->[" + newVersion + "]");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);       
}

}
```

AreaMonitoringProvider:

```
public class AreaMonitoringProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final String TAG = "AreaMonitoringProvider";

private AreaMonitoringDB mDB;

private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.data.AreaMonitoringProvider";

private static final String BASE_PATH = "AreaMonitor";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
        + "/" + BASE_PATH);



private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
        UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, 0);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDB = new AreaMonitoringDB(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(AreaMonitoringDB.TABLE_NAME);


    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(mDB.getReadableDatabase(),
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}


@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {

   SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();

    int rowsAffected;

     String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
     StringBuilder modSelection = new StringBuilder(AreaMonitoringDB.ID
             + "=" + id);

     if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
         modSelection.append(" AND " + selection);
     }

     return rowsAffected = sqlDB.update(AreaMonitoringDB.TABLE_NAME,
             values, modSelection.toString(), null);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


 }
```

In my Main Activity I update it using:

```
                            ContentResolver cr1 = getContentResolver();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(AreaMonitoringDB.COL_FLAG, flag);
                            values.put(AreaMonitoringDB.COL_NUMBER, stringArea);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+flag+" "+stringArea, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            cr1.update(AreaMonitoringProvider.CONTENT_URI, 
                            values, 
                            AreaMonitoringDB.ID + "="+ 0, 
                            null);
                            Log.e("TEST PROVIDER"," NUMBER "+ AreaMonitoringDB.COL_NUMBER);
                            Log.e("TEST PROVIDER"," ID "+ AreaMonitoringDB.ID );
```

LOGCAT:

```
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column
   : AreaMonitor: , while compiling: UPDATE AreaMonitor SET enable1=?,tel_number=?
   WHERE _id=AreaMonitor AND _id=0
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.nat
   ive_compile(Native Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<in
   it>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile
   Sql(SQLiteProgram.java:146)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile
   AndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:367)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acqui
   reAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:253)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execu
   teUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:83)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update
   WithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1829)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update
   (SQLiteDatabase.java:1780)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at com.notfall.AreaMonitoringProvider.update(Are
   aMonitoringProvider.java:73)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.upd
   ate(ContentProvider.java:233)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.content.ContentResolver.update(Conten
   tResolver.java:847)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at com.notfall.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActi
   vity.java:221)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$Butt
    onHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
   va:99)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
   d.java:4025)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
   Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:4
   91)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
   rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
   eInit.java:599)
   E/AndroidRuntime( 3831):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

@SLUKIAN 
CAn you please check this code for CursorIndexOutOdBounds Exception

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        final String[] projection = { AreaMonitoringDB.ID, AreaMonitoringDB.COL_FLAG,AreaMonitoringDB.COL_FLAG2,AreaMonitoringDB.COL_FLAG3,AreaMonitoringDB.COL_NUMBER };
        final String id = "%1%";
         cur = cr.query(AreaMonitoringProvider.CONTENT_URI, 
                projection, 
                AreaMonitoringDB.ID + " LIKE ?", 
                new String[] {id}, 
                null);

        cur.moveToFirst();
```

LOGCAT :

```
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0          requested, with a size of 0
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at   android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:421)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:117)
 03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
 03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:96)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at com.notfall.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:324)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3112)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11956)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
  03-21 02:11:42.590: E/AndroidRuntime(7665):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add the `Logcat` with the full `Exception` stacktrace.

Comment: Hello, I updated the question with the Logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ContentProvider` `update()` method you should have:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
int rowsAffected;

return rowsAffected = sqlDB.update(AreaMonitoringDB.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
}
```

If you want to query for a specific `Uri` contact then use the `UriMatcher`(to add specific Uris to match) and switch for its values in the `update()` method.

Comment: hey thank you..this worked..:)..No column ecxeption is gone..but when i try to query the database I get CursorIndexOutOfBOundsException..:I will update my Question..can you please help me.

Comment: @HelloWorld In the query where you have `AreaMonitoringDB.ID + " LIKE ?"` try to replace it with `AreaMonitoringDB.ID + " = ?"`.

Comment: @HelloWorld First of all the `ID` column should be declared like `integer primary key autoincrement`. Second, do you have values in the database(and values with the id equal to 1 )?(If not then the cursor is empty and don't access it). Third try the above code with a simple `id` string `String id = "1";` and NOT with id ="%1%".

Comment: I set the values as u said for "first" and "third" point. But could you please explain a little more about the second point? About values in the Datatasbe? I dont have values with Id equal to 1.

Comment: Do i have to use init() method  to intialize all the fields in AreaMonitoringDB class?

Comment: @HelloWorld If you don't values in the database with the id 1 then your cursor will be empty and you must not access it for rows. After you make the query check if the cursor is empty (if (cur.getCount > 0)). If it is empty then you don't access it with `moveToFirst`, `moveToNext`(etc) because you don't have any values to show.

Comment: @slukian..I initialised the DB (init() in AreaMonitoringDB) with id=o and other values....so when I query for id=0 it works...then i try to add values with id=1 to the database...and then when I query i get the same exception....the row with Id=1 is not created when i call update()...

Comment: It worked finally..i initialised the database with both id=0 and id=1...thanks a lot for your help...:)

Answer (score 1):

Increment your database version. It should delete the current table and re-create it to solve any missing column:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 11;  //previously 10
```

Comment: It worked perfectly in my case. I'm not up-voting because I think that what I had it's a different issue (but same SQLiteException): in fact I changed the number of columns thorough app versions. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have introduced new column for the existing table.
First uninstall the old application from emulator and re install the application again. I think this will work.

Comment: Hello, I have not added any new columns. Im running the application on lenovo tablet. I tried to uninstall and re install the app many times..also changed the databse version everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to `COL_FLAG2` and `COL_FLAG3` fields are set as `NOT NULL` and when updating the table the values for these columns are not specified.

Try with either removing the `NOT NULL` constraint from Table definition or provide values when updating the table.

Comment: hey, i tried giving values to COL_FLAG2 and COL_FLAG3 when updating...but same exception...